# Set userAgent with selenium-webdriver/firefox (NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, user-agent

I have a code running browser using 'selenium-webdriver'. It runs on Ubuntu.

I have to override userAgent so it will look like the requests from the browser are coming from Windows (i.e. the value of **User-Agent** requests' header).

Here is my NodeJS code:

```
var firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');

var profile = new firefox.Profile();
profile.setPreference('general.useragent.override', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36');

var options = new firefox.Options().setProfile(profile);
console.log(profile);
var driver = new firefox.Driver(options);

driver.get('http://whatsmyuseragent.com/');
```

The userAgent that appears is

> Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101
>   Firefox/49.0

Here is the *console.log(profile);* output (as you can see - **'general.useragent.override': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36'** appears there, but doesn't effect the browser settings):

```
Profile {
  preferences_: 
   { 'browser.dom.window.dump.enabled': true,
     'browser.laterrun.enabled': false,
     'browser.newtab.url': 'about:blank',
     'browser.newtabpage.enabled': false,
     'browser.startup.page': 0,
     'browser.startup.homepage': 'about:blank',
     'browser.startup.homepage_override.mstone': 'ignore',
     'browser.usedOnWindows10.introURL': 'about:blank',
     'dom.max_chrome_script_run_time': 30,
     'dom.max_script_run_time': 30,
     'dom.report_all_js_exceptions': true,
     'javascript.options.showInConsole': true,
     'startup.homepage_welcome_url': 'about:blank',
     'startup.homepage_welcome_url.additional': 'about:blank',
     webdriver_accept_untrusted_certs: true,
     webdriver_assume_untrusted_issuer: true,
     'app.update.auto': false,
     'app.update.enabled': false,
     'browser.displayedE10SNotice': 4,
     'browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting': false,
     'browser.EULA.override': true,
     'browser.EULA.3.accepted': true,
     'browser.link.open_external': 2,
     'browser.link.open_newwindow': 2,
     'browser.offline': false,
     'browser.reader.detectedFirstArticle': true,
     'browser.safebrowsing.enabled': false,
     'browser.safebrowsing.malware.enabled': false,
     'browser.search.update': false,
     'browser.selfsupport.url': '',
     'browser.sessionstore.resume_from_crash': false,
     'browser.shell.checkDefaultBrowser': false,
     'browser.tabs.warnOnClose': false,
     'browser.tabs.warnOnOpen': false,
     'datareporting.healthreport.service.enabled': false,
     'datareporting.healthreport.uploadEnabled': false,
     'datareporting.healthreport.service.firstRun': false,
     'datareporting.healthreport.logging.consoleEnabled': false,
     'datareporting.policy.dataSubmissionEnabled': false,
     'datareporting.policy.dataSubmissionPolicyAccepted': false,
     'devtools.errorconsole.enabled': true,
     'dom.disable_open_during_load': false,
     'extensions.autoDisableScopes': 10,
     'extensions.blocklist.enabled': false,
     'extensions.checkCompatibility.nightly': false,
     'extensions.logging.enabled': true,
     'extensions.update.enabled': false,
     'extensions.update.notifyUser': false,
     'javascript.enabled': true,
     'network.manage-offline-status': false,
     'network.http.phishy-userpass-length': 255,
     'offline-apps.allow_by_default': true,
     'prompts.tab_modal.enabled': false,
     'security.csp.enable': false,
     'security.fileuri.origin_policy': 3,
     'security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy': false,
     'signon.rememberSignons': false,
     'toolkit.networkmanager.disable': true,
     'toolkit.telemetry.prompted': 2,
     'toolkit.telemetry.enabled': false,
     'toolkit.telemetry.rejected': true,
     'xpinstall.signatures.required': false,
     'xpinstall.whitelist.required': false,
     'general.useragent.override': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36' },
  nativeEventsEnabled_: true,
  template_: undefined,
  port_: 0,
  extensions_: [] }
```

I tried to set the **general.useragent.override** manually (following http://www.howtogeek.com/113439/how-to-change-your-browsers-user-agent-without-installing-any-extensions/) - it works! Though it doesn't effect the settings of the instances that are opened with selenium-webdriver driver (anyway I prefer to be able to set it pragmatically).

Any idea why doesn't it work for me?

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know the **user Agent can't be set programatically with firefox**. Instead I suggest you to **use [chromium](https://www.simplified.guide/ubuntu/install-chromium-browser)** with the [ChromeDriver](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads). As the following python example shows you can easily set the User Agent to your desired value.

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--user-agent=\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36\"')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

driver.get('https://www.whatsmyua.info/')
```

If you want to change your userAgent during runtime of your script you will need to start a new driver instance.